# What is meant by the “Yogic Slumber” of Bhagwan Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, bhagavata-purana, dharma-shastras, yog-nidra

I heard a description of Bhagwan Vishnu which says that the he is in “Yogic Slumber”

What exactly happens in this condition?Please explain “yogic slumber” in detail.

Comment: Become Vishnu - to experience! Certain things are unexplainable! Like, screaming exactly as your first scream or screeching like an Owl with precision. 
Human biology is way not enough!

Answer (score 0):

Padma Purana:UK:175.:

> 5. “[Sri Lakshmi said.]: **O revered one, You, despite being the sustainer of the world, you being indifferent (passive) towards your glory, are sleeping on this milky ocean, what’s the reason behind this?”.**
> 6. “[Lord Vishnu said]: **O you of beautiful face, I’m not sleeping, rather, by the vision which sees (follows) the truth, I am contemplating by being fixed (nimagna) in my true form of Lord Maheshvara (Lord Shiva)“.**
>
> 14-15. “[Sri Lakshmi said.]: O Hrishikesha! You alone are always to be meditated upon by the self-controlled ones. Therefore, **I have a great curiosity to hear from you, about that which is higher than you.** O Achuta, tell me if there is something different from you who are the lord, the creator, and the destroyer of the worlds”.
>
> 16-18. “[Lord Vishnu said]: O goddess (Lakshmi), **this my body is illusory and not real,** and is augmented with the mass of the acts of creation, maintenance and withdrawal. O dear one, the nature of the self is different form this. It is without duality and unity. It is free from existence and non-existence; and without beginning or end. It is pure consciousness, has acquired luster, is beautiful due to great joy, **is the form of the Ishvara (lord),** can be known only through the unity with the self, and this is what is told in the Gita”.
>
> 19-20. “Hearing the words of him of an unlimited lustre, she having doubt to contradictory statement said: ‘If you are highest joy, and not known through speech and mind, then how does Gita make you known. Remove this doubt of me!'”.
>
> 20-26a. “[Lord Shiva said]: Having heard the proper words of Lakshmi, the lord told her the Gita, the vision leading one towards the self, along with an historical account. “O great lordess, I am the ‘self’ differentiated in two ways, – as higher and lower. **The higher is a witness, attributeless, partless, Shiva. As the lower one, I am ‘panchavaktra (of five faces)’ it also remains in two forms. I, Maheshvara, am the self,** am to be explained through the distinction in words and meanings, as, through the words of the Gita, my strong noose of the nature of objects in the worldly existence, is completely cut off; **since (realization of my two forms) ‘Panchavaktra’ and ‘Maheshvara’, are dependent on its study“.** Hearing these words of him (which were) the great ocean of essence of the Gita, those afraid of the worldly existence know it through the difference between this and that. Lakshmi asked thus to him. He told her about the Mahatmayam (greatness) along with the corresponding historical accounts (stories) in its major and minor details.”.
>
> 26b-29. “[Lord Vishnu said]: O you, beautiful lady, I’ll tell you about my firm existence in the Gita. **The five chapters are the five faces in order. The (next) ten chapters are the (ten) hands; one is the belly, and the (remaining) two are the lotus like feets.** Thus the eighteen chapters are the divine forms of words. It, destroying great sins, should be known through knowledge only. Therefore, he, the very intelligent one, who studies a chapter, or half of it, or a verse of a half-verse is liberated like ‘Susharma’”.

Atharvashika Upanishad 2:1.:

> **“The pranava (the sound of Om) makes all the souls to bow before it. It is the one and only one which has to be meditated upon as the four Vedas and the birth place of all devas.** One who meditates like that goes away from all sorrows and fears and gets the power to protect all others who approach him. **It is because of this meditation only that Lord Vishnu who is spread every where, wins over all others. It is because Lord Brahma controlled all his organs and meditated upon it, he attained the position of the creator. Even Lord Vishnu , parks his mind in the sound (Om) of the place of Paramathma (ultimate soul) and meditates upon Îsâna. , who is most proper to be worshipped. All this is only proper in case of Îsâna.”.**

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..